# Execute as another user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a problem with select to msdb tables.
I have a login = "MyUser" and User = "MyUser" for this login. This user is member for few roles.

When I log on by managemnet studio as "MyUser" and call this select:

```
 SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

I get all result as I wish.

When I log on by my account (admin permissions) and call this select:

```
EXECUTE AS USER ='MyUser'
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs
```

I get Error

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database
> 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.

I checked user context by

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), USER_NAME()
```

I got correct result

```
MyUser    MyUser
```

Could you help me find where the problem is?

Comment: Which databases are there with MyUser as user? Is it possible you are using different databases each time, although the same user name is used?

Comment: The fact that you are using 3 part naming implies you aren't connected to `msdb`. You'll want to therefore use `EXECUTE AS LOGIN`, as a `USER` is a database object; it has no context in a different database. Or, otherwise, connect to the `msdb` database and use 2 part naming.

Comment: Super - That is work:
EXECUTE AS LOGIN

Now I would like transfer this tema....
Is it posibile run this query for user without login? 

btw. the user is in booth databases (MYDb and msdb) with the same login :-)

Comment: Try `EXECUTE AS LOGIN ='MyUser';`.  `EXECUTE AS USER` is sandboxed to the current database (unless it's THRUSTWORTHY) .

Comment: *"Is it posibile run this query for user without login?"* As a I said "Or, otherwise, connect to the `msdb` database and use 2 part naming." The fact that the `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` worked is a clear indication you *weren't* connected to `msdb` but some other database.

Comment: I can not connect to msdb directly....I will Explain it:
I Have primary Db.....for example MyDb. There is MyUser with permissions to diff objects
I wolud like create procedure with select to msdb, but I dont want get permission to msdb for this user. 
I plan create user without login (MyUserWithoutLogin) with permissions an the procedure create with caller  MyUserWithoutLogin
The user MyUser Can Call this procedure but can not connect directly to msdb

I hope every think is clear :-)

Comment: Then i would suggest you use certificates and sign your procedure, @DavidMrazek . Seems like what we have here is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).